# Drools: insertLogical and retract

Tags: java, drools, decision-tree, expert-system

This is a follow up on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887456/decision-trees-and-rule-engines). I have a decision tree in the following form: [image: Decision tree diagram]

and I want to transform it into rules in Drools Expert. The use of `insertLogical` has been [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887456/decision-trees-and-rule-engines). Drools documentation says [this](http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.1.1.34858.FINAL/drools-expert/html_single/index.html#d0e5121) about `insertLogical`:

> `insertLogical(new Something())`; is
>   similar to insert, but the object will
>   be automatically retracted when there
>   are no more facts to support the truth
>   of the currently firing rule.

The fact that these objects are retracted is useful (as I'll have tens of thousands of objects in memory and each will create a bunch of these). There's also a method `retract(object)`, which removes an object from working memory. When I get to an end node and remove (`retract`) the base object that would get there (following the decision tree), does it also remove all these *temporary* objects created with `insertLogical` during the traversal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience the answer is **No**, the only object you've pointed to will be retracted from Drools working memory while all the cross-object references will be kept in JVM memory. You could even re-inject retracted object back if you keep object's reference somewhere.